# Unable to upload multiple files with SAP UI5 FileUploader

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm using the following code to upload multiple documents to the server.

```
 var docFileUploader = new sap.ui.unified.FileUploader({
    name : fileUploaderName,
    uploadOnChange: false,
    uploadUrl: uploadUrlStr,
    multiple:true,
    additionaldata : nodeObjId ,
    fileSizeExceed: function (oEvent) {
        var sName = oEvent.getParameter("fileName");
        var fSize = oEvent.getParameter("fileSize");
        var fLimit = oFileUploader.getMaximumFileSize();
        Messenger().post({
            message: "File: " + sName + " is of size " + fSize + " MB which exceeds the file size limit of " + fLimit + " MB.",
            type: 'error',
            showCloseButton: true
        });
    },
    uploadComplete: function (oEvent) {                                                             
        var sResponse = oEvent.getParameter("response");
        console.log(sResponse);
        var thisDlg = this.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
        console.log(thisDlg);

        if (sResponse) {
            var m = /^\[(\d\d\d)\]:(.*)$/.exec(sResponse);
            if (m[1] == "200") {
                uploadSuccess = true;
                thisDlg.setBusy(false);
                console.log("The document has been uploaded successfully");
                            setTimeout(function() { Messenger().post("The document has been uploaded successfully");}, 100);
            } 
            else {
                thisDlg.setBusy(false);
                setTimeout(function() { Messenger().post({
                     message: 'Oops! Error in document upload. <br>Please try again or contact your administrator.',
                     type: 'error',
                     showCloseButton: true
                });},100);
            }
        }

        thisDlg.setBusy(false);
        console.log("The document has been uploaded successfully");
        setTimeout(function() { Messenger().post("The document has been uploaded successfully");}, 100);

        thisDlg.close();    
        thisDlg.destroy();

        setTimeout(function() { reloadPage(attrGrpName); }, 100);
    }
});
```

The controller part is as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "doc/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public @ResponseBody String uploadDoc(@RequestParam("uploadDoc-data") ObjectId nodeId,
        @RequestParam(value = "uploadDoc", required = true) MultipartFile[] files, @RequestParam String userId, @RequestParam String passwd) {
    if (files != null) {
        return service.uploadDoc(nodeId, files[0], userId, passwd);
    } else
        return "No files found to upload";
}
```

Even if I use files[0] gives me an **ArrayIndexOutofBound 0 Exception**. It means the MultipartFile[] is returning an empty array only. I was able to upload one file without multiple attributes. The problem arises if I set the multiple attributes to 'true'. What am I missing? Please help me.

Comment: I had same issues, I would recommend you to use Upload Collection https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.UploadCollection/samples

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.UploadCollectionForPendingUpload/code/Page.controller.js

Comment: same link has examples, select one example, then click on right top corner to see the code also.